# Can I add an additional hdd with a new windows 7 install to and exisiting ubunbtu 14.04 LTS PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a HP DC8000 SFF PC with a 250GB HDD and 8GB RAM running ubuntu 14.04LTS which i use for Steam linux games and it works very well with the Nvidia GeForce GTX 750 Ti graphics card installed.

I really want to be able to run some windows Steam games (No Mans Sky actually is the only one!) I know I can install a fresh ubuntu and leave existing windows OS in place but i dont want to have to re-install my current version on ubuntu as ive got lots of mods for other games ive compiled and it would take forever to re-build.

so, can i add an additional HDD and install windows on it so I get the option to choose between the ubuntu HDD or windows HDD in the grub boot menu (dual boot it i guess?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible.

First disconnect the hdd with Ubuntu on it from your computer (pull out wires).
Second connect the hdd on which you want to install Windows.
Now install Windows.
Reconnect the Ubuntu hdd.
Go into BIOS and make sure the boot order is set to boot the Ubuntu hdd first.
Start up the computer and boot into Ubuntu. In Ubuntu open a terminal and in the terminal type: `sudo update-grub`. Fill in your password and let the script do its work. Reboot the computer. Now you should get a grub menu where you can choose which OS to boot, Windows or Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for this,  its exactly the sort of thing i'm trying to achieve,  ill give this a try in the next day or 2 and repost the result...  thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

You can add new hdd. After adding hdd:

- you can edit your grub from ubuntu if you know your new hdd dev name

  or
- you can use grub repair flash or cd to update your grub.